# Python: Syntax Error?

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement

```
A=int(input('Enter the first of three numbers: '))
B=int(input('Enter the second of three numbers: '))
C=int(input('Enter the third of three numbers: '))
list=[A,B,C]
SL=sorted(list)
if SL[0]<0:
    if SL[1]-1==SL[0]:
        print (list('they are good'))
    else: print (list('not good'))
elif SL[2]-1==SL[1]:
    print (list('they are good')
else: print (list('not good'))
```

I keep getting a syntax error on the last line in between else and : and i have no idea why it's wrong when i have the exact same line 3 lines above. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You should really post the exact error message.

Comment: it was just the bracket, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an end parenthesis on the second to last line, it should be:

```
    print (list('they are good'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a trailing ')' on the second-to-last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
elif SL[2]-1==SL[1]:
    print (list('they are good')
```

Missing a closing `)` at the end of the print-statement.